# How to use the file cache with Laravel Multi tenancy

Tags: php, laravel, caching, multi-tenant

I'm using the following multi tenancy package: 
https://laravel-tenancy.com/docs/hyn/5.3

Laravel: 5.7

I current made the caching tenant aware by changing the config on the switched event.

```
Event::listen(Switched::class, function (Switched $event) {
   config(['cache.stores.file.path' => storage_path('framework/cache/' . $event->website->uuid)]);
});
```

This works well when doing a command like:

```
php artisan tenancy:run my:caching-command --tenant=2
```

This does not work well:

```
php artisan tenancy:run my:caching-command
```

In this case only a cache dir is created for the first tenant. When debugging it, I found that the config is actually properly updated for each tenant. However the cache driver is not using the new path...

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to rebuild the cache instance with:

```
app()->forgetInstance('cache');
```

If lateron in your code the cache instance is accessed via `app('cache')`, it will be rebuild with your current config.